# Site separation per customer using spring mvc and maven3

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, maven-3

Just a general question on any techniques used to seperate your web application for customer specific requirements.  At the moment I have one web application but I need to add new functionality for one customer thats not needed by another.  I know spring 3 comes with new support for profiles but I'm just curious if anyone has had a similar problem and how they went about solving it particularly using spring mvc and maven as a build management tool

Comment: Sounds role-based to me.

Comment: Its not as much a role based query as it is a customer based question.  For example if i want to run a function for a user on company B's version of the app but not a company A's user.  This is also an issue with jsp pages.  Where one customer might have different options than another customer.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this would be as follows:

- Have a web assembly module. This module will build a war file containing the proper features extracted into separate modules simply defined as dependencies. My advice is to have a separate web assembly project per client. This way you will keep things neat for yourself, avoid mix-ups (such as releasing features to clients who haven't paid for them) and have an overall easier maintenance.
- Furthermore decide whether to do your version separation at the level of the `version` tag or `classifier`:

  - The `version` tag you can use in order to separate things in branches.
  - The `classifier` tag you can also use to separate configurations specific to your clients.

Comment: This is sort of what I had in mind, any common jsp's or resources would have to be copied first before building the war id imagine.

Comment: Yes, this would make things tidier and not just that -- you will be able to trace the dependencies and manage them. I've done this many times, as before I've worked for companies which had complex Ant build scripts building everything for all of the clients. This is just error-prone and every now and then certain features would end up with another client. The way I propose you have full control over things.